# Mongodb не подключается к nodejs в контейнере

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

Я столкнулся с странной проблемой при подключении MongoDB, запущенного в отдельном контейнере из контейнера nodejs, при попытке подключения к MongoDB появляется следующая ошибка:
[image: ошибка docker]

Мой `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Мой `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    links:
    - mongo
    - redis

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

config Mongodb

```
 mongoose: { // MongoDB
    // uri: mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options
    uri: `mongodb://localhost:27017/${DB_NAME}`,
    options: {
    },
    seed: {
      path: '/api/models/seeds/',
      list: [
        {
          file: 'user.seed',
          schema: 'User',
          plant: 'once' //  once - always - never
        },
        {
          file: 'example.seed',
          schema: 'Example',
          plant: 'once'
        }
      ]
    },
  },
```

Comment: Вам требуется указать ссылку
```uri: `mongodb://mongo:27017/${DB_NAME}`,```

Comment: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/10/13/437da8f228f15bc99866c9997d00ef77-full.png 
Вот что я теперь получаю

Comment: хз, ошибки на скриншоте не увидел - там видно что к базе у Вас приложение подключается успешно вроде как

Comment: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/10/14/426ad5b0c851799cb698885c15c79c4e-full.png Програ должна так запустится!